# ¿Por qué lstname es NULL?

Tags: c, punteros

```
int main(){
    char *name;
    char *lstname;

    printf("Nombre: ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("Apellido: ");
    scanf("%s", lstname);

    printf("%s\n", name);
    printf("%s\n", lstname);
}
```

Al imprimir "name" sí me muestra bien el contenido, pero al imprimir "lstname" me marca un error: **violación de segmento (`core' generado)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en que no reservas memoria. En este ejemplo he reservado para 20 caracteres pero puedes ponerle mas ( o menos ).

- **malloc()** es una función para reservar memoria
- **free()** es una función para liberar la memoria asignada a esa variable

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *name = malloc(20*sizeof(char));
    char *lstname = malloc(20*sizeof(char));

    printf("Nombre: ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("Apellido: ");
    scanf("%s", lstname);

    printf("%s\n", name);
    printf("%s\n", lstname);

    free(name);
    free(lstname);

    return 0 ;
}
```